# System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#

i only get the exception in the XAML Editor in visual studio 2010, when i debug the application everything works fine and that resource gets loaded successfully, however the problem only happens in the XAML editor, is there a way to disable such exceptions?

```
    <!--ViewModels-->

    <!--This View Model Causes the problem-->
    <SharedViewModels:DatabaseViewModel x:Key="DatabaseViewModel"/>
```

and thats how i use it in the main window

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DatabaseViewModel}}"
```

Comment: Can you post the xaml code of the window that causes this error?

Comment: i get the exception in every window and usercontrol in the application and even the external libraries that are in no way related to this resource, and one thing is when i try to bind to that static resource it shows up in the suggestion list! and the app works fine and i could use that resource in there

Comment: Still we need some code to be able to understand what is going here... Post some relevant xaml code (from the resource for example, and how you reference it)

Comment: Please show some code on your XAML issue

Comment: @vishnu i added some XAML

Comment: @RononDex please check the XAML

Comment: Try using only `{StaticResource DatabaseViewModel}` when using it

Comment: @RononDex that wont work , not even when debugging, the way it is now works when debugging but fails in the editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue as described in [Troubleshooting WPF Designer Load Failures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in the **UserControl and Custom Control Resources at Design Time** section:

> By default, UserControl and custom control resources that are available at run time may not be available at design time. When you add your custom controls and user controls to a Page or Window on the design surface, an instance of the control is created. Resources in App.xaml are not available to UserControl and custom control instances loaded on a page or window.
>
> To make your resources available at design time, factor them into a separate resource dictionary and include the dictionary in App.xaml and your control's XAML. Change all StaticResource references to DynamicResource references. The following code example shows how to share a resource dictionary so that its resources are available at design time.

So basically in addition to including your resources in `App.xaml` you also need to include them in your XAML to make them available at design time. In my experience using `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource` does not seem to be necessary.