# Could not find ObjectDataProvider when localizing wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project along with main project in my solution. I want to localize the content in this xaml file in this project.

I use the ways that have been discussed here [How to change UI language using resource dictionary at run time in MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407108/how-to-change-ui-language-using-resource-dictionary-at-run-time-in-mvvm).

However I could not find ObjectDataProvider in any way.

```
<UserControl xmlns:languageHelper="clr-namespace:XX"
  <UserControl.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources" ObjectType="{x:Type languageHelper:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

and I use this code to find ObjectDataProvider but i coulnt get it through

```
public static ObjectDataProvider ResourceProvider
    {
      get
      {
        if (m_provider == null)
          m_provider = (ObjectDataProvider)System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("Resources");
        return m_provider;
      }
    }
```

```
Resources.Culture = culture;
        ResourceProvider.Refresh();
```

It shows System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException: ''Resources' resource not found.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that you are creating your **ObjectDataProvider** in your UserControls resources. I think you have to create that in your App.xaml file

here is an example:

```
<Application.Resources>    
    <ResourceDictionary>           
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

               <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type languageHelper:CultureResources}" 
                    MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Hej, you are exactly right. Actually I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538368/system-windows-resourcereferencekeynotfoundexception which helped me solve the problem shortly before your answer. But the problem is what you pointed. Thanks!

Comment: @Cactus I'm happy that I could help. You can mark the answer as Correct answer if you want.

Comment: @ Zer0 Yes please, I was trying to mark it but I couldn't.